# One click on image inside cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two images inside one cell of uitableview, these images shows to images from an external server and each tag of them has an id of item which this image represent, I need if I clicked on this image move user to new view controller which show details of this item, I force a problem, where user need to double click to show details instead of one click, the following my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! prodctCell
        Id1stMove =  cell.image1st.tag
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(ItemsController.imgTap))
        cell.image1st.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        cell.image1st.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let cell1 = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! prodctCell
        Id2ndMove =  cell1.image2nd.tag
        let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(ItemsController.imgTap1))
        cell1.image2nd.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
    }


func imgTap()
    {
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as? testViewController
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController!)
            navController.setViewControllers([secondViewController!], animated:true)
            self.revealViewController().setFront(navController, animated: true)
            revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)
        secondViewController?.movmentId = Id1stMove
        updateCount(itemId: Id1stMove)

    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Do you want to require a double-tap? Or is the behavior not happening until you perform a double-tap?

Comment: I need one tap to movement to another view not double tap

Comment: Why are you adding tap gestures inside the `didSelectRowAt` method? That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to execute this code in cellForRowAt indexPath instead did select.

As you said you want to use image id from the tag value I suggest below change in addition of adding code in cellForRowAt indexPath:

Change tapGesture code as below:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(imgTap(tapGesture:)))
```

And imgTap function:

```
 func imgTap(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imgView = tapGesture.view as! UIImageView
        let idToMove = imgView.tag
       //Do further execution where you need idToMove

    }
```

Comment: I do that previously, but I want using image tag which content the id of item, so when I use your method the tag value were the value of last image, but I need value for each of them.

Comment: Many Thanks That's Work to me.
But I have another problem if you can resolve that to me,

Comment: whats other problem? I can try :)

Comment: @AliJalil downloading. But can you please quickly check whats the iOS version of the device and version of iOS deployment target (You can find it under Build Settings of your app target).

Comment: Both of them iOS 10.2

Comment: @AliJalil I could not run even in simulator, it keep on giving me random errors :( :( :(

Comment: I send you email, can you communicate by it? :{ :( 
please

Comment: Okay, I also replied to you.

Answer (score 10):

Yesterday itself I created sample and tried.I got the solution.But I could not post my answer immediately as I had some work.

Now I will give you my answer.I don't expect reputation for my below answer.

When you click or tap the image first time,it navigates.

You don't need to add TapGestureRecognizer for imageView in didSelectRowAt method.You need to add TapGestureRecognizer for image View in cellForRowAt method.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    let mobiles: [String] = ["iPhone", "Android"]
    let images: [String] = ["iPhone.png", "android.png"]
    @IBOutlet var tableViewImageTapping: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.mobiles.count
    }

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.mobiles[indexPath.row]
        let strImageName = images[indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: strImageName)
        cell?.imageView?.tag = indexPath.row
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell?.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell?.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        return cell!
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is selected
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped table view cell index is \(indexPath.row).")
    }

    // method to run when imageview is tapped
    func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let imgView = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        print("your taped image view tag is : \(imgView.tag)")
        if (imgView.tag == 0) //Give your image View tag
        {
            //navigate to next view
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
```

Output Screenshot

[image]

Printed results are

When you click the first image in first click

[image]

Then when you click the second image in first click

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is as @sanjana answer.
But I have another problem if you can answer it.

Comment: This does not work. Perhaps Apple made a change or there is some configuration you omitted? The `didSelectRowAt` is called instead of the gesture recognizer on the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please don't use force unwrap `as! prodctCell`
2. Please use name swift naming conventions
3. Don't use `.tag` cell is usually reused it might break in some edge cases

Now back to your question, you already have a custom cell that holds the image.
you have several possibilities

1. Add the gesture recogniser to the imageView 
   you can change that to a button
2. Add a button over the image view (no title or image for it)

Then create an `@IBAction` for the button/gesture recogniser, and a delegate method that will call the main viewController where you can pass all the data you need from the cell to instantiate the second VC

**Update**
I would advice against adding the logic of handling the tap in the `cellForRow` the viewController is not meant to handle and manage his child logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the gesture recognizers in the "did select row at index path" method, this means that the user must select (tap) a cell for the gesture recognizers to be assigned to the images, and then the user must tap the image for those recognizers to react by calling "imgTap()", those are the two taps.

What you should do instead is assign the gesture recognizers in the "cell for row at index path" method, so when you create each cell you also create the gesture recognizers, that way when the user taps an image for the first time the tap is recognized and "imgTap()" is called.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(ItemsController.imgTap))
    cell.image1st.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
    let tapGesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(ItemsController.imgTap))
    cell.image2nd.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)

    return cell
}
```

I also recommend changing the code a little so you can call "imgTap()" with a parameter (the id of what was tapped), instead of having 2 methods "imgTap()" and "imgTap1()".

Comment: I do that previously, but I want using image tag which content the id of item, so when I use your method the tag value were the value of last image, but I need value for each of them. 
How can I use Id.

Comment: Just configure the cell (as the comment says) before doing the rest, so it has the new images along with the new tags, and then obtain the new tags.

Comment: The cell configuration is whatever you currently have right now in the "cell for row at index path" method, have you tried creating the gesture recognizers at the end of this method?